# ERROR: "activate does not accept more than one argument:" (while activating env using condo)

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I played with the VENVs from a terminal without conda, and but now I'm trying with conda as well. I installed mini-conda and created the v-env, and now I'm trying to activate the v-env by this code.....

```
(base) J:\jaimin (E)\Programming Practice\Machine Learning and Data Science\Sample Project\env>conda activate J:\jaimin (E)\Programming Practice\Machine Learning and Data Science\Sample Project\env
```

and conda showed this error.....

```
activate does not accept more than one argument:
['J:\\jaimin', '(E)\\Programming', 'Practice\\Machine', 'Learning', 'and', 'Data', 'Science\\Sample', 'Project\\env']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a pathname with spaces, you will need to wrap the argument in quotes:

```
conda activate "J:\jaimin (E)\Programming Practice\Machine Learning and Data Science\Sample Project\env"
```

It'd be easier in the long run to not use spaces though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. At the end  - best to use environment names without whitespaces.